# Python input num

Tags: python

```
def get_num_players() -> int:
    num_players = int(input("Enter the number of players (1 to 4): "))
    while True:
        if num_players < 1 or num_players > 4:
            print("Invalid number of players. Please enter a number between 1 and 4.")
            num_players = int(input("Enter the number of players (1 to 4): "))
        elif num_players >= 1 or num_players <= 4:
            break
        else:
            print("Invalid number of players. Please enter a number between 1 and 4.")
            num_players = int(input("Enter the number of players (1 to 4): "))
        
    return num_players
```

i am tryint to ask the player to input the number of player in the input,but when the users type empty or string ,it will pop up EOFError: EOF when reading a line.What can i do to fix that error?

Comment: I cannot seem to reproduce your issue as posted. The EOFError usually appears when no data is sent to the input function, even pressing the Enter key does not trigger this exception. Maybe it's a coincidental error?

Comment: did the try except solve your problem? if so accept an answer pls

Comment: Please show the exact stack trace (with the EOFError). Are you sure you're running this interactively? If you run this with standard input stream (stdin) redirected from some device or file, you could get EOFError. You can also induce EOFError with Ctrl-D in an interactive environment

Comment: Can't reproduce your problem, only raise `ValueError` if an empty or string be input. But no matter what it is, you can wrap your code with try-except clause to catch the error.

Answer (score 1):

I think the error generated when the user enters a string or nothing is actually:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

right? This is what I get.

This is because `int` will generate an error if the input string is cannot be interpreted as an integer.

You can get around this by using a try-except block. Get the input first, then try to convert it to an integer.

Also, I think you mean `elif num_players >= 1 and num_players <= 4:`, not `elif num_players >= 1 or num_players <= 4:` for the success condition.

Try the following:

```
def get_num_players() -> int:
    while True:
        user_input = input("Enter the number of players (1 to 4): ")
        try:
            num_players = int(user_input)
            if num_players >= 1 and num_players <= 4:
                return num_players
            else:
                print("Invalid number of players. Please enter a number between 1 and 4.")
        except:
            print("Invalid number of players. Please enter a number between 1 and 4.")
```

Answer (score 1):

To handle the possibility of the user entering non-integer or empty input, you can use a try-except block to catch the ValueError that occurs when trying to convert the input to an integer.

```py
def get_num_players() -> int:
    while True:
        try:
            num_players = int(input("Enter the number of players (1 to 4): "))
            if 1 <= num_players <= 4:
                break
            else:
                print("Invalid number of players. Please enter a number between 1 and 4.")
        except ValueError:
            print("Invalid input. Please enter a valid integer.")

    return num_players
```

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule you'll you should **always** validate user input that needs to be converted to some type other than str.

When you need an integer, passing the string to *int()* and checking for a ValueError exception is a good strategy.

However, in this case, you're only interested in a few specific values - i.e., 1, 2, 3 & 4

You also often want some way to indicate that the program should be ended by user input. A reasonable technique is to allow the user to just enter an empty value.

This version of your function will return either an int in the range 1->4 or None if the user provided empty input (just hit Return)

```
def get_num_players() -> int | None:
    while np := input("Enter the number of players (1 to 4): "):
        if np in {'1','2','3','4'}:
            return int(np)
        print("\aInvalid number of players")
    # implicitly return None on empty input
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe a try and except statement that is triggered when your input fails because of an input type that can't be casted to integer will help you:

```
def get_num_players() -> int:
try:
    num_players = int(input("Enter the number of players (1 to 4): "))
except:
    print("Wrong type of Input!")
    num_players = int(input("Enter the number of players (1 to 4): "))
while True:
    if num_players < 1 or num_players > 4:
        print("Invalid number of players. Please enter a number between 1 and 4.")
        num_players = int(input("Enter the number of players (1 to 4): "))
    elif num_players >= 1 or num_players <= 4:
        break
    else:
        print("Invalid number of players. Please enter a number between 1 and 4.")
        num_players = int(input("Enter the number of players (1 to 4): "))
    
return num_players
```

Comment: You only need one call to input() in a properly constructed program. You have 4

Comment: I admit it isn't a pretty solution, i just quickly added the try and except to the code provided by the questioneer.